# Prevent Maps API from geocoding coordinates

Tags: google-maps

I have a mobile website that launches google maps navigate function via a url, for example [example url](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate&destination=51.685733,-4.924571) however when maps launches, the coordinates have been changed to a street address.  A lot of the places that I use for navigation are in the middle of fields, and the items to be located are small (1m x 1m) and need to be located at night.  How can I prevent the maps API from converting my lat & lon to a street address or location of nearest POI, and actually navigate to the lat & long specified.

If the lat & lon are entered directly into maps, it works correctly and navigates exactly to the point specified.

Answer (score 0):

The directions service is going to take you to the nearest place it knows about (which is most likely on a road).  If you need to go somewhere from there, add the desired location to the map, then draw a polyline to it from the end of the route returned.

Related question: [Google Maps API directionsService.route different from Google Maps Directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596050/google-maps-api-directionsservice-route-different-from-google-maps-directions)